# Changes to files takes 10-20 minutes to register

Tags: cache

When I make changes to and .php or .phtml files in my Magento directory it is taking at least 10 minutes for these changes to take affect (making development difficult).

I have cleared /var/cache and /var/session which does not help, I have disabled the compiling which has not helped, and I have cleared my apc cache, all to no avail.

I assume there is more caching somewhere, any idea on what?

Comment: The possible answers are endless, you might want to share here your environment configuration here to check the possible causes.

Comment: I would assume, that your hoster has some caching in front of the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APC was apparently not installed properly. I don't know exactly what was going on, but disabling APC completely cleared up the issue.